# How transform double signed value to Hex signed value

Tags: java, hex

Looking for a solution to resolve my problem, I've found just Hex signed to int value transformation, but not the inverse case.

I've tried this:

```
  float grades = -32.33f ;
  System.out.println("grades: "+grades);

  double radians = Math.toRadians(grades);
  System.out.println("rad: "+radians);

  radians = radians * 100000000;
  System.out.println("rad * 10^8: "+radians);

  String hex = Double.toHexString(radians);
  System.out.println("signed to hex: "+hex);
```

with output:

```
grados: -32.33
rad: -0.5642649791276998
rad * 10^8: -5.642649791276998E7
signed to hex: -0x1.ae8000f4d5a59p25
```

But I'm expecting get:

```
FCA30001
```

In this answer [Java negative int to hex and back fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845230/java-negative-int-to-hex-and-back-fails) I found that `Double.toHexString(radians);` gave me an unsgined value, may be this is the problem. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I'm trying do the inverse operation of:

- 1) FCA30001 to signed int is: -56426495,
- 2) -56426495*10^8 is -0.564264 radians,
- 3) Now converting radians to grades is -32.33.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15073682/557153

Comment: You might be looking for `Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(radians))`?

Comment: Why do you expect to get FCA30001?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29

Comment: @immibis, I'd update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking long/int overflow: 10<sup>8</sup> needs 23 bits + 2π 3 bits < 32, so int is fine.

```
long radiansUp8 = 0xFFFF_FFFFL & (long)(radians * 100_000_000);
String hex = Long.toHexString(radiansUp8);
```

Though we took an int, because of the sign, it was placed in a long, and masked with Integer.MAX_VALUE.

---

***For precision:***

As you know `double` is only an approximation of a sum of powers of 2. Multiplying by 10<sup>8</sup> enlarges the approximation error. And in your code even 4 bytes `float` is used.

```
double grades = -32.33;
```

should be a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, I test this code, but the finnal output is `signed to hex: fca2ffff`, in some part I'm losing digits may be. I'm expecting get `fca30001`

Comment: The approximation error of the initial grades is multiplied by more that 10<sup>8</sup>. Added a hint to the answer.