# Get Value from Apdu Response

Tags: android, nfc, apdu

I store a length value in buffer accoreding to:

```
Short len=(short)128;
buffer[1]=(byte)len
```

in debug mode I see this value in buffer:
[image]

in android app I get apdu response in this code

```
byte[] result=isodep.transceive(....)//... is Apdu command
```

and get result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Py2.png) .
It is -128 but I want to get 128.
what Can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java and unsigned Bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073562/java-and-unsigned-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote int i=result[1] & 0xFF and It answers.